How do I add a Multilevel dropdown to a Django template?
I am trying to add a dropdown to my navbar in base.html that shows multiple categories from a store. Each of these categories has a sub-category associated with it. I've created a model in Django that maps this relationship like so.
models.py
class CategoryView(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

And I'm passing this model to the template using context processors as so
def categoriesdropdown(request):
    catg = CategoryView.objects.filter(parent=None)
    context = {'catg':catg}    
    return context

Now I am trying to display these categories and sub-categories as a multilevel dropdown using bootstrap. I have tried implementing mostly all solutions from the answers here:
Bootstrap 4: Multilevel Dropdown Inside Navigation
Bootstrap dropdown sub menu missing
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/dropdown-multilevel/
But nothing seems to work.
Below is the dropdown from my template.
base.html
<div class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Categories</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    {% for category in catg %}
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ category.title }}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu2" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu1">
                {% for subcategory in category.children.all %}
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">{{ subcategory.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

I can see that all the categories and sub-categories are listed properly in the dropdown, however my sub-categories appear right below the categories and not as a next level dropdown.

Note: The dropdown toggle appears as is and doesn't work.
base.css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
  }
  
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu2 {
top: 10%;
left: 100%;
margin-top: -1px;
}
  
.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu2 {
    display: block;
} 

How do I get the category toggles to work and only display the sub-categories when the toggle is clicked or hovered over?

To check what the problem is, you'll also need a link to the sample page you created.

I have tried some adjustments with the code you have provided and i couldn't try it in my system as i didnt have the entire source code. so i kindly request you to please try it and reach out to me if it didn't work
Updated HTML code for bootstrap 4:
<div class="nav-item dropdown">
<a href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Categories</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    {% for category in catg %}
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu{{ category.id }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ category.title }}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu{{ category.id }}">
                {% for subcategory in category.children.all %}
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">{{ subcategory.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

Updated CSS for Bootstrap 4:
    /* Style for the multilevel dropdown */
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu.show {
    display: block;
}

The key changes i have done in your code are:

Submenu position: The submenu should appear next to its parent. The CSS sets top: 0 and left: 100%, making it appear to the right.

Hover behavior: The submenu will show on hover with dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu { display: block; }.

Bootstrap 4 CDN: If you're using Bootstrap 4, make sure the right version is linked in your base template:


